# Access gnome-shell messaging tray using keyboard

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, messaging-tray

Is there a keyboard shortcut to access the gnome-shell messaging tray? E.g. For responding to incoming IM, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Gnome 3.6 and up

This extension has not yet been updated for Gnome 3.6 But the functionality it provided for the message tray is now a built in feature of Gnome 3.6.

#### Gnome 3.4 and earlier

A GNOME extension has been developed to enable keyboard access to messaging tray.

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/313/helpful-keybindings/

You can, by default, use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to display the messaging tray and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate the messaging tray. You can also configure the keyboard shortcut to your wish.

[image]

Comment: This is good for showing the messaging tray, but I wish there were a way to access it interactively by keyboard. i.e. to emulate clicking on a notification.

Comment: I'll try to check if there are any similar extensions that does it for you.

Comment: Ah, I've played around with it a bit more, and it seems that you can access the notifications if you catch them immediately (e.g. with super+space), but once they disappear back down into the tray, you can only see them (e.g. with super+m), but not activate them.

Comment: So, if you can elongate the duration of the message appearing, you have your problem solved. Good luck :D

Comment: But that's not ideal either, as having the pop-up persistent obscures the bottom of my window. Oh well... I guess I'll spend the extra half second moving my hand to the mouse. Sigh. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a built in feature of Gnome 3.6's [Message Tray](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Design/Guidelines/MessageTray).

You can customise the shortcut to open the tray, and then use arrow keys to navigate the various notifications.